# Invalid field ContactPhone on SObject under Case Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, case, sobject

I have a Visualforce page which has a Case object. It's pretty standard. However when I try to refer the ContactPhone by the code, using `<apex:outputText value="  {!Case.ContactPhone}"></apex:outputText>`, the editor throws an error saying:

> Invalid field ContactPhone for sObject Case.

I want to create a button that can show a pdf of the Case Object. So I created a Visualforce Page and tried to create a button that relates to the VF Page. But I got stuck here. Could anybody tell me what should I do? How can I refer to this field? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use: `Contact.Phone`

```
<apex:outputText value="  {!Case.Contact.Phone}"></apex:outputText>
```

as ContactPhone is available from Contact, basically it behaves as a formula field taking value from the Contact record.

Again, if the Visualforce is using **StandardController** of Case it works fine

```
<apex:outputText >{!Case.ContactPhone}</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Thx Santanu, but I am using StandardController rit now <apex:page standardController="Case" renderAs="pdf" showHeader="false" applyhtmltag="false" >  but <apex:outputText >{!Case.ContactPhone}</apex:outputText> doesn't work on me.

Comment: Plus, do you know why the value of Case Owner doesn't show correctly, my code is like this:  <apex:outputText value="{!Case.Owner}" />   the data type of this value is Lookup(User,Queue)  does it matter?  and I meet the same situation with Contact Name and Account Name. Their codes are:  <apex:outputText value="{!Case.Contact}" />         and         <apex:outputText value="{!Case.Account}" />    just like Case Owner.  Thanks very much